# How to debug the job array for SLURM through two loops?

Tags: arrays, loops, variables, slurm, sbatch

I need to submit many jobs for the cluster by slurm. Each job takes different input files from different folders. My problem is the output is incomplete, and outputs after the first 8 combinations keep overwriting the previous ones. I suspected the job array is not correctly created from the combination of the two variables provided. Here is my code sample:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --array=1-57%12         
#SBATCH --time=0            
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=12
#SBATCH --mem=6G
#SBATCH --output=/storage/proj/AltSp/logs/Lastz_Intron.log

DIR_OUT="/storage/proj/AltSp/data/annotation/Lastz/Br"
mkdir -p ${DIR_OUT}

QUERY="/storage/proj/AltSp/data/annotation/Introns.txt"
Species=/storage/proj/AltSp/data/Species.list   #3 lines: Br\nBn\nBo\n

# Chroms=/storage/proj/AltSp/genomes/Br/chromosomes.list # 20 lines: A1 ~ A20, one at a line
# Chroms=/storage/proj/AltSp/genomes/Bn/chromosomes.list # 18 lines: B1 ~ B18, one at a line
# Chroms=/storage/proj/AltSp/genomes/Bo/chromosomes.list # 19 lines: C1 ~ C19, one at a line

# REF is changing according to spc and chr

for spc in $(cat ${Species}); do
    chr=$(head -n ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} genomes/${spc}/chromosomes.list | tail -1)
    REF="/storage/proj/AltSp/genomes/${spc}/${chr}.fasta"
    
    lastz ${REF} ${QUERY} K=3000 H=2200 --format=axt+ > ${DIR_OUT}/introns_vs_${spc}-${chr}.axt
done

Outputs files are:

    introns_vs_Br-A01.axt
    introns_vs_Br-A02.axt
    ...
    introns_vs_Br-A08.axt
```

**spc** is in a single file, one name/string in a line;
**chr** is in several files, also one name/string in a line in each file;
**REF** is changing according to the **spc** and **chr** of different combinations to give 57 files in total.
The 57 jobs [array] are submitted with **sbatch** to run 12 jobs at a time in my allocation.

What was wrong with the **SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID** job array created by looping through the two variables **spc** and **chr** in my sample code that over-writes the output?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the issue might be associated with how you obtain `$chr`. To verify, add `${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}` to your job output file. For example, like this:

```
lastz ${REF} ${QUERY} K=3000 H=2200 --format=axt+ > ${DIR_OUT}/introns_vs_${spc}-${chr}-task${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}.axt
```

So, if you get 57 outputs generated, then the issue is associated with how you obtain `$chr`.

Comment: @j23Thanks! Found out the problem is the line:   
**chr=$(head -n ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} genomes/${spc}/chromosomes.list | tail -1)**
When **spc** takes new folder, **SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID** does not reset to start from the beginning of the chromosomes.list, causing the **chr** to use the old value.

Comment: @Yifangt That's good to hear :-) If the answer helped, you can accept the answer ;-)